# Where is the extra 3px coming from?

Tags: html, css

I added a white background to show where it is. How do I remove that extra 3px? I don't want to set the height to a specific amount because I want it to be proportional and scale (max is 400x250px). Currently the height is 253px, I want it to be the image size which is 250px.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2odqw5u/

HTML:

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <figure class="entry">
        <img src="http://www.robertfikesiv.com/images/Gallery/Graphic/thumb/Bad-Panda2.jpg"/>
        <div class="hover">TEST</div>
    </figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background: #000;
}

.portfolio{
    padding: 0px 10px 0px;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.figure{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.entry{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.hover { 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.9) ; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    bottom:0px; 
    right:0px; 
    opacity:0; 
    -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-out; 
    -moz-transition:all .2s ease-out; 
    -ms-transition:all .2s ease-out; 
    -o-transition:all .2s ease-out; 
    transition:all .2s ease-out; 
} 

.entry:hover .hover{
    opacity: 1;
} 

figure > div {
    padding-top:25%;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: did you try inspecting the elements that why it's happening!

Comment: The 3px are the baseline from whitespace. You can check if you put font-size:0 into the portfolio class. Or you remove any whitespace inside the portfolio div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You image is `inline`. Hence it is aligned with the baseline. Hence the white space. Of the many ways to kill that space are:

1. `vertical-align:middle` your image. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/e2odqw5u/10/
2. `display: block` your image. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/e2odqw5u/11/
3. `font-size: 0px;` on your `figure` and `font-size: npx` on your `div`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/e2odqw5u/12/

Answer (score 1):

just add `display: block` to the `img`:

```
.entry img{
  display: block;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e2odqw5u/3/)

Comment: but from where did that extra space came from?

Comment: theres no reason to float the image, just need to overwrite the default `inline-block` that gets applied to `img` tags